# Como dar setTimeout em submit de form? Se é que existe como

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte codigo e gostaria de saber como faço para que `após o click no button enviar` apareça a mensagem **Login realizado com sucesso!** e depois de 3 segundos o formulário seja enviado:

```js
function validarLogin(strLogin,strSenha) {

        if(strLogin == "") { 
            document.getElementById('login').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.frmLogin.txtLogin.focus();
            document.getElementById('strong1').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('sucesso').style.visibility = "hidden";
            return false;
        }
        else if(strSenha == "") { 
            document.getElementById('senha').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.frmLogin.txtSenha.focus();
            document.getElementById('strong2').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('sucesso').style.visibility = "hidden";
            return false;
        }
        else { 
            document.getElementById('sucesso').style.visibility = "visible";
            return true;
        }   
                                                        
    }                                                           

    function input1() {
        var strLogin = document.getElementById('login').value; 
        if(strLogin !== "") {
            document.getElementById('strong1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('login').style.borderColor = "green";
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function input2() {
        var strSenha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
        if(strSenha !== "") {
            document.getElementById('strong2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('senha').style.borderColor = "green";
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function delay() {
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        form.submit();
        return validarLogin();
    }

    function forml() {
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(delay, 2000);
        }); 
    }
```

```css
#box {
        background-color: #28B2A1;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 6px; 
        margin-top: 25%;
    }
    strong {
       display: none;
       color: red; 
    }
    .btn {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #sucesso {
        visibility: hidden;
        color: #28B2A1;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 6px;        
    }
    samp{
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="box">
                <h4 class="text-center" id="sucesso">Login realizado com sucesso!</h4>
                <form name="frmLogin" id="form" action="validar_login_js.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validarLogin(txtLogin.value,txtSenha.value);">
                    <samp><label for="login">LOGIN</label></samp>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="txtLogin" value="Fulano" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="input1()">
                    <strong id="strong1">Preencha corretamente o campo Login!</strong id="strong1"><br>
                    <samp><label for="senha">SENHA</label></samp>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="txtSenha" value="123456" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="input2()">
                    <strong id="strong2">Preencha corretamente o campo Senha!</strong><br><br>       
                    <p class="text-center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar" id="enviar">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" name="btnLimpar" value="Resetar"></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes é preciso chamar a função `forml()` que ativa o `addEventListener` no carregamento da página. Também é dispensável a função `delay()`, já que você pode fazer tudo no evento:

```
(function forml() {
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = document.getElementById('form');
      var txtLogin = document.getElementById('login').value;
      var txtSenha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
      if(validarLogin(txtLogin,txtSenha)) setTimeout("form.submit()", 3000);
  }); 
}())
```

Altere o valor do `setTimeout` de 2000 para 3000 (3 segundos).

Você tem também que enviar os parâmetros da mesma forma que está fazendo no `onsubmit` do `form` para retornar a validação, como mostra o trecho do código:

```
...
var txtLogin = document.getElementById('login').value;
var txtSenha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
if(validarLogin(txtLogin,txtSenha)) setTimeout("form.submit()", 3000);
...
```

Assim só irá submeter o formulário caso o retorno da função `validarLogin` seja `true`.

Vamos ver funcionando:

```js
function validarLogin(strLogin,strSenha) {

        if(strLogin == "") { 
            document.getElementById('login').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.frmLogin.txtLogin.focus();
            document.getElementById('strong1').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('sucesso').style.visibility = "hidden";
            return false;
        }
        else if(strSenha == "") { 
            document.getElementById('senha').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.frmLogin.txtSenha.focus();
            document.getElementById('strong2').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('sucesso').style.visibility = "hidden";
            return false;
        }
        else { 
            document.getElementById('sucesso').style.visibility = "visible";
            return true;
        }   
                                                        
    }                                                           

    function input1() {
        var strLogin = document.getElementById('login').value; 
        if(strLogin !== "") {
            document.getElementById('strong1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('login').style.borderColor = "green";
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function input2() {
        var strSenha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
        if(strSenha !== "") {
            document.getElementById('strong2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('senha').style.borderColor = "green";
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

   (function forml() {
     var form = document.getElementById('form');
     form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var form = document.getElementById('form');
         var txtLogin = document.getElementById('login').value;
         var txtSenha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
         if(validarLogin(txtLogin,txtSenha)) setTimeout("form.submit()", 3000);
     }); 
   }())
```

```css
#box {
     background-color: #28B2A1;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 6px; 
     margin-top: 25%;
 }
 strong {
    display: none;
    color: red; 
 }
 .btn {
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #sucesso {
     visibility: hidden;
     color: #28B2A1;
     background-color: #fff;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 6px;        
 }
 samp{
     font-weight: bolder;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="box">
                <h4 class="text-center" id="sucesso">Login realizado com sucesso!</h4>
                <form name="frmLogin" id="form" action="validar_login_js.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validarLogin(txtLogin.value,txtSenha.value);">
                    <samp><label for="login">LOGIN</label></samp>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="txtLogin" value="Fulano" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="input1()">
                    <strong id="strong1">Preencha corretamente o campo Login!</strong id="strong1"><br>
                    <samp><label for="senha">SENHA</label></samp>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="txtSenha" value="123456" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="input2()">
                    <strong id="strong2">Preencha corretamente o campo Senha!</strong><br><br>       
                    <p class="text-center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar" id="enviar">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" name="btnLimpar" value="Resetar"></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Muito bom dvd, valeu mesmo!

Comment: Estou fazendo umas alterações para ficar melhor ainda.

Comment: Pronto. Fica melhor assim, sem a função delay() que não precisa. Abs!